# Button IsMouseOver trigger on Path not working

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have button with custom content containing a Path element.
The Path's Fill property is wired with the button's IsMouseOver property.

Can any anybody point out whats wrong with the code & why the trigger is not firing.

Below is the complete sample code -

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="8"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <Path Width="10"
                Height="10"                      
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                Fill="Orange"
                Stretch="Uniform"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                Data="M7.1999998,0L16,8.7999997 24.799999,0 32,7.1999998 23.2,16 32,24.799999 24.799999,32 16,23.2 7.1999998,32 0,24.799999 8.7999997,16 0,7.1999998z">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <TransformGroup.Children>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                        </TransformGroup.Children>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
                <Path.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" Value="True" >
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF5733" ></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" Value="False" >
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Orange" ></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Path.Style>
            </Path>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remove the property `Fill` from `Path` and set the Orange value only in `Style`. 
Instead of implementing two `Trigger`, you can use only one and set the `False` value in `Style` by `Setter` directly. This default value will be set if `Trigger` doesn't match.

```
<Button Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="8"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <Path Width="10"
          Height="10"                      
          Margin="0,0,0,0"
          Stretch="Uniform"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
          Data="M7.1999998,0L16,8.7999997 24.799999,0 32,7.1999998 23.2,16 32,24.799999 24.799999,32 16,23.2 7.1999998,32 0,24.799999 8.7999997,16 0,7.1999998z">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <TransformGroup.Children>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                </TransformGroup.Children>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
        <Path.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Orange" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}" Value="True" >
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF5733" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Path.Style>
    </Path>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here is another way**

```
 <Button x:Name="btn"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="8"
                Width="100"
                Height="100"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <Path Width="50"
                  Height="50"
                  Margin="0,0,0,0"
                  Data="M7.1999998,0L16,8.7999997 24.799999,0 32,7.1999998 23.2,16 32,24.799999 24.799999,32 16,23.2 7.1999998,32 0,24.799999 8.7999997,16 0,7.1999998z"
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                  Stretch="Uniform">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <TransformGroup.Children>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                        </TransformGroup.Children>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
                <Path.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">

                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF5733" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btn, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Orange" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Path.Style>
            </Path>

        </Button>
```